# Assigning shortcut key to the Zoom to selection function is not working

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am trying to change the shortcut key cntrl + j (which is standard) to for example q, in the settings I see its changed but in the Attribute table where I want to use it to select a row and then zoom to selection its not working, cntrl + j is working.

How can I change this and use a different shortcut key?

Answer (score 2):

The shortcuts from settings only applies to the main QGIS window. Other windows (i.e. the attribute table) have their own shortcuts assigned. I don't think this can be changed from the GUI but you can using a bit of Python.

Load the attribute table(s) and then open up the **Python Console** from the main QGIS window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>). Then use something like the following:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QKeySequence
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable' ]
for tables in attrTables:
    for x in tables.children():
        if x.objectName() == 'mActionZoomMapToSelectedRows':
            x.setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Q))
            x.setToolTip('Zoom map to the selected rows (Q)')
```

---

Now you should be able to zoom to the selected feature using <kbd>Q</kbd>.

*Note: this will no longer work if the attribute table is closed.*