# Assigning QGIS Attribute Table commands, like zoom to selected feature, to shortcut key?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Is there a way to assign QGIS Attribute Table commands, like zoom to selected feature, etc a shortkey?

If I try to assign them a shortkey using setting >> shortkey. Attribute table commands doesn't show up.

Comment: in `settings-> Keyboard shortcuts` have this options, invert selection,zoom to selected feature etc..

Comment: Those are for Canvas Features not attribute table features

Comment: Ah,you need use python maybe for this feature I think

Comment: @Someone191 - Perhaps this post might help: [assigning a shortcut key to the Zoom to selection function is not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286914/assigning-a-shortcut-key-to-the-zoom-to-selection-function-is-not-working)